# Accessing protected members in a derived class

Tags: c++

I ran into an error yesterday and, while it's easy to get around, I wanted to make sure that I'm understanding C++ right.

I have a base class with a protected member:

```
class Base
{
  protected:
    int b;
  public:
    void DoSomething(const Base& that)
    {
      b+=that.b;
    }
};
```

This compiles and works just fine.  Now I extend Base but still want to use b:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  protected:
    int d;
  public:
    void DoSomething(const Base& that)
    {
      b+=that.b;
      d=0;
    }
};
```

Note that in this case `DoSomething` is still taking a reference to a `Base`, not `Derived`.  I would expect that I can still have access to `that.b` inside of `Derived`, but I get a `cannot access protected member` error (MSVC 8.0 - haven't tried gcc yet).

Obviously, adding a public getter on `b` solved the problem, but I was wondering why I couldn't have access directly to `b`.  I though that when you use public inheritance the protected variables are still visible to the derived class.

Comment: Check out http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm (Note: don't use that stuff in production code).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A class can only access protected members of instances of this class or a derived class. It cannot access protected members of instances of a parent class or cousin class.

In your case, the `Derived` class can only access the `b` protected member of `Derived` instances, not that of `Base` instances.

Changing the constructor to take a `Derived` instance will solve the problem.

Comment: Do you mean to say here that we can access the protected members from our own objects not from base class's objects? If yes, then why is so?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: You can only access your base class' protected members in an instance of your type, not a cousin type.  For example, `Button` cannot access a protected property from `Control` on a `TextBox`.

Comment: `You can only access your base class' protected members in an instance of your type, not a cousin type` You have again written the same statement which you wrote above. Please have a look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139824/how-to-access-protected-members-in-a-derived-class

Comment: @SLaks What do you mean by "Changing the constructor to take a Derived instance will also solve the problem." ?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron: Because then you'll be accessing a protected member on your own type.

Comment: It's not a constructor (if you mean changing `void Derived::DoSomething(const Base& that)` to `void Derived::DoSomething(const Derived& that)`).

Comment: @SLaks but why instance of Base class have access to pivate members of other instance of this Base class?

Comment: How about an accessor method in base class, virtual and protected, that you can call from the derived class passing a reference to another instance of the base class or a derived class?

Comment: The lucidity of your answer is awesome. Suggestion: change the wording of the last line to "Changing the `DoSomething` prototype to ..."

Answer (score 13):

`protected` members can be accessed:

- through `this` pointer
- or to the same type protected members even if declared in base
- or from friend classes, functions

To solve your case  you can use one of last two options.

Accept Derived in Derived::DoSomething or declare Derived `friend` to Base:

```
class Derived;

class Base
{
  friend class Derived;
  protected:
    int b;
  public:
    void DoSomething(const Base& that)
    {
      b+=that.b;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  protected:
    int d;
  public:
    void DoSomething(const Base& that)
    {
      b+=that.b;
      d=0;
    }
};
```

You may also consider public getters in some cases.

Comment: Seems like a C++ language mistake to have to say this-> for an accessible member with no name hiding.  Java got it right!\?

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned, it's just the way the language works.

Another solution is to exploit the inheritance and pass to the parent method:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  protected:
    int d;
  public:
    void DoSomething(const Base& that)
    {
      Base::DoSomething(that);
      d=0;
    }
};
```

Comment: I gave a bad example in the question, but I cannot call Base::DoSomething because the DoSomething actually goes about doing it's thing differently when it comes into a Derived rather than a Base.

Answer (score 4):

You have access to the protected members of `Derived`, but not those of `Base` (even if the only reason it's a protected member of `Derived` is because it's inherited from `Base`)

Comment: This doesn't work.  Consider "You have access to the `private` members of `Derived`." and the implications for inherited `private` members of `Base`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with **static_cast< const Derived*>(pBase)->Base::protected_member** ...

```
class Base
{
  protected:
    int b;

  public:
    ...
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  protected:
    int d;

  public:
    void DoSomething(const Base& that)
    {
      b += static_cast<const Derived*>(&that)->Base::b;
      d=0;
    }
    void DoSomething(const Base* that)
    {
      b += static_cast<const Derived*>(that)->Base::b;
      d=0;
    }
};
```

Comment: If the dynamic type of `that` is not (cv) `Derived`, [the behavior is undefined](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.static.cast#11.sentence-5).

Comment: But, for this case, b is alway a data member of base class!

Comment: Or better, you can use:
  b += static_cast<const Derived*>(that)->Base::b;

Answer (score 2):

Following the [hack for stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523178/how-to-print-out-all-elements-in-a-stdstack-or-stdqueue-conveniently/4523216#4523216) I wrote a small code which seems to solve the problem of accessing the protected members in derived class

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
protected:
    int a;
public:
    void dosmth()
    {
        a = 4;
    }

    void print() {std::cout<<"a="<<a<<std::endl;}
};

class D: private B
{
public:
    void dosmth(B &b)
    {
        b.*&D::a = 5;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    B b;
    D d;
    b.dosmth();
    b.print();
    d.dosmth(b);
    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
a=4
a=5
```

Comment: It turns out that my example is nearly the same as one posted above. I also wandered that it works. From my opinion it to casting to a derived type, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  protected:
    int d;
  public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
      b+=this->b;
      d=0;
    }
};

//this will work
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `this` pointer to access protected members

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  protected:
    int d;
  public:
    void DoSomething(const Base& that)
    {
      this->b+=that.b;
      d=0;
    }
};
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. The derived class cannot access "b" of the base class as it is declared as protected (this is what the user asked in the first place). This code will generate a compiler error.

Comment: What a non-answer. It's the `b` of `that` that is the problem. And adding `this->` is not only unrelated but also a complete no-op because it's implied if omitted. I wish people would know a tiny bit about a language and test any code they write before posting it as an answer.

Comment: This works, at least in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Best and simplest answer. Works better than everything above. I only wonder why i need "this" to access the protected members of a base class?