# How to access protected method in base class from derived class?

Tags: c++, protected, derived-class

Here is a sample of code that annoys me:

```
class Base {
  protected:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  private:
    Base *b; /* Initialized by constructor, not shown here
                Intended to store a pointer on an instance of any derived class of Base */

  protected:
    virtual void foo() { /* Some implementation */ };
    virtual void foo2() {
      this->b->foo(); /* Compilator sets an error: 'virtual void Base::foo() is protected' */
    }
};
```

How do you access to the protected overrided function?

Thanks for your help. :o)

Comment: I don't think your implementation is quite right. Why do you have an instance of Base as a member variable? this->b->foo() would be trying to call a pure virtual method.

Comment: This program shouldn't compile. You cannot instantiate an abstract class....Unless `b` is pointing to an instance of some other class derived from `Base`.

Comment: I omitted precision: the Derived::b attribute is intended to store any instance of derived classes from Base

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247671/accessing-protected-members-in-a-derived-class (that's about members instead of methods, but they are not very different)

Comment: C++ calls them member functions, not methods (although some people use the latter, but in my experience that just leads to linguistic arguments), and the concepts are the same for member functions and member variables, so: duplicate of [Accessing protected members in a derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247671/accessing-protected-members-in-a-derived-class)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Protected members in a base-class are only accessible by the current object.
Thus, you are allowed to call `this->foo()`, but you are not allowed to call `this->b->foo()`. This is independent of whether `Derived` provides an implementation for `foo` or not.

The reason behind this restriction is that it would otherwise be very easy to circumvent protected access. You just create a class like `Derived`, and suddenly you also have access to parts of other classes (like `OtherDerived`) that were supposed to be inaccessible to outsiders.

Comment: Thanks, I now clearly understand the reasons of the restriction... That would be a security hole... big one!

Comment: Please don't think of it as a security hole. Access modifiers do not provide any security, you could just read the memory location if you wanted the data.

Comment: right, this isn't about "security" but instead about telling users which parts of the class they can use and rely on (i.e. which parts are not implementation details that might vanish/change at any moment). sure, they shouldn't read that stuff, and will have to use acrobatics with stuff like `offsetof` to do so, but it's definitely not about security in the sense of physically preventing access to data - only documenting intended usage, semantics, and stability of the API.

Answer (score 7):

Normally, you would do it using `Base::foo()`, which refers to the base class of the current instance.

However, if your code needs to do it the way you're trying to and it's not allowed, then you'll need to either make foo() public or make Derived a friend of Base.

Answer (score 5):

One solution would be to declare a static protected function in `Base` that redirects the call to the private / protected function (`foo` in the example).

Lets say:

```
class Base {
protected:
    static void call_foo(Base* base) { base->foo(); }
private:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    Base* b;
protected:
    virtual void foo(){/* Some implementation */};
    virtual void foo2()
    {
        // b->foo(); // doesn't work
        call_foo(b); // works
    }
};
```

This way, we don't break encapsulation because the designer of `Base` can make an explicit choice to allow all derived classes to call `foo` on each other, while avoiding to put `foo` into the public interface or explicitly turning all possible subclasses of `Base` into friends.

Also, this method works regardless of whether `foo` is virtual or not, or whether it is private or protected.

[Here](https://ideone.com/EGHhG5) is a link to a running version of the code above and [here](https://ideone.com/gnFwdW) another version of the same idea with a little more business logic.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit fragile, but with the classes you defined here, won't this work?

```
virtual void foo2() {
  reinterpret_cast<Derived *>(this->b)->foo(); 
}
```

The reinterpret_cast points at the VTABLE for the base object, and calls it through this members accessor.

Answer (score 0):

You call base functions explicitly with the scope operator (Base::foo()).  But in this case, the Base class doesn't define foo (it's pure virtual), so there's actually no function to execute when you say `this->b->foo();` since b is a pointer to Base and not Derived.

Comment: But the OP's code doesn't refer to the base class of the current instance. He's accessing another instance, which presumably is a derived class that implements the pure-virtual function. (Otherwise, the instance could not be created.)

Comment: @Jonathan Wood I understand what you're saying, but just going from the code he's posted, it looks like he's trying to instantiate an abstract base class (Base) and call a pure virtual function (Base::foo()), which is a no-no (as GWW and 341008 also mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

> How do you access to the protected
>   overrided function?

--- from where?

You can access a protected member only via inheritance (apart from the methods of the same class). Say for example you have a `class Derived1` which inherits from `Derived`, then objects of `Derived1` can call `foo()`.

EDIT: [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e761de5s.aspx) on protected access specifier.