# Inheritance of nested class and visibility scope

Tags: c++, inheritance, nested-class

Consider following code:

```c
namespace base {
class Base {
    protected:
        class Nested {
            protected:
                Base* base;

            public:
                Nested(Base* _base) : base( _base ){}

                virtual void test() {
                    base->foo();
                    /*
                     * hmm.. we can use protected methods
                     */
                    base->bar();
                }
        };

    protected:
        Nested* nested;

        void bar(){}

    public:
        void foo(){}

        virtual void test() {
            nested = new Nested(this);
            nested->test();
        }
};
};

namespace inherited {
class Base : public base::Base {
    public:
        Base()
            : base::Base() {}

    protected:
        class Nested : public base::Base::Nested {
            public:
                Nested( inherited::Base* base )
                    : base::Base::Nested( base ) {}

            public:
                virtual void test() {
                    base->foo();
                    /*
                     * hmm.. and now they are not accessible
                     */
                    // base->bar();
                }
        };

    public:
        virtual void test() {
            foo();
            bar();

            nested = new Nested(this);
            nested->test();
        }
};
};
```

My qestions is why we have access to protected methods/properties of `base::Base` from `base::Base::Nested` but no access to the same methods/properties of `inherited::Base` from `inherited::Base::Nested`?

The only thing I could suppose is that `base::Base` is a kind of *global scope* for `base::Base::Nested` thus they are accessible. `inherited::Base` is a kind of *global scope* for `inherited::Base::Nested` and protected members of `base::Base` are not accessible. However, public inheritance should not change scope of visibility and the reason of access inability is unclear for me.

Comment: Your mind works so strangely. inherited::Base? Ok anyway, For the purposes of this example strip 80% of this code and make Base, BaseNested, Derived, and DerivedNested classes and get rid of all the functions that don't demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Please try to avoid the unnecessary cruft (namespaces, too many members) in your code and make it compilable (no strange undefined macros, no missing includes). Otherwise a good question.

Comment: Is there any reason to assume that this is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672438/how-to-access-protected-method-in-base-class-from-derived-class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be the type of the stored pointer and not access rights. Consider this:

```
class B {
protected:
  void bar();
};

class D : public B {
public:
  void call() {
    this->bar(); // works
    static_cast<B*>(this)->bar(); // does not work
  }
};
```

The situation is similar when you try to call `bar` through the
pointer that is stored in the base.

You can work around this issue by down-casting base, but I would strongly object to that.

Comment: Finally I get it. I'm trying to access to protected method `base::Base::bar()` from `inherited::Base::Nested::test()` because `base::Base::Nested::base`(and `inherited::Base::Nested::base`) is pointer of type `base::Base` and not of type `inherited::Base`. Now it is clear for me.

Comment: @ilardm Please refer to the answer of jogojapan for the relevant standard quotes. This behavior seems unintuitive but is necessary so access restrictions cannot be trivially circumvented.

Answer (score 1):

§11.4/1 has this to say on access to protected members (highlighting of relevant parts by me):

**An additional access check beyond those described earlier in Clause 11 is applied when a non-static data member or non-static member function is a protected member of its naming class (11.2) As described earlier, access to a protected member is granted because the reference occurs in a friend or member of some class C.** If the access is to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), the nested-name-speciﬁer shall denote C or a class derived from C. All other accesses involve a (possibly implicit) object expression (5.2.5). **In this case, the class of the object expression shall be C or a class derived from C.**

This is not easy to interpret. Thankfully, the Standard gives a number of examples to illustrate the meaning, and one of them seems to be exactly your case (unless I misunderstood something in your code, which is quite possible):

*(Note I have removed irrelevant parts of the examples, and renamed some elements for the sake of simplicity.)*

```
class B {
  protected:
  int i;
  static int j;
};

class D : public B {
  void mem(B*);
};


void D::mem(B* pb) {
  pb->i = 1;                // ill-formed
  i = 3;                    // OK (access through this)

  /* The following cases are not directly relevant: */
  B::i = 4;                 // OK (access through this, qualification ignored)
  int B::* pmi_B = &B::i;   // ill-formed
  int B::* pmi_B2 = &D::i;  // OK
  j = 5;                    // OK (because j refers to a static member)
  B::j = 6;                 // OK (because B::j refers to a static member)
}
```

In other words, in

```
pb->i = 1;
```

the member `i` is found through `pb`, a pointer to the base class, hence the *naming class* is `B`. But the access occurs from `mem()`, which is a member of `D`. `B` is not identical to `D`, nor is it derived from it (although `D` is derived from `B`), so the access is not allowed.

But in

```
i = 3
```

the member is found through `this`, hence the naming class is `D` and access is allowed.