# Why can't I access the protected function in the derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected

I have a Base class and derived another class from it. The derived class has a function which takes as an argument `const Base&` and calls its protected member function. I get an error saying that the function being called is protected in that context. I'd like to know why that happens and can I  solve it without making the protected function in base class `public`.

```
class Base {
protected:
    void call() const {}
};

class C : public Base {
public:
    void func(const Base& b) {
        b.call();
    }
};
```

I tried adding `using Base::call` in the derived class but that didn't help

Comment: Because `b` is another object. You can only call `public` function in other objects. However if you want to call `call` in `this` object it would be possible. So e.g. `void func() const { call(); }` would be perfectly fine.

Comment: So the question from us now really becomes: Why do you pass `b` as argument?

Comment: This is just for the sake of example

Comment: If you're only passing `b` as an argument for the sake of example, what's the issue? Don't you have an actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11634082/485343 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4672888/485343

Comment: Class C can only access the protected part of its own Base class. `b` could easily be part of a `class A : public Base` that C has no access to.

Comment: that will work `class C : public Base {  void func(const C& c) {       c.call(); } };`  . Why? Because C++ standard says so. see:  https://eel.is/c++draft/class.protected

Comment: Summary: `protected` is weird. There are good reasons for it, but it's still weird.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -- re: "Why do you pass `b` as an argument?" -- because this is a **minimal reproducible example**. That's what people who ask questions are supposed to do.

Comment: @molbdnilo -- this is a **minimal reproducible example**. That's what a good question should do. The question is "why doesn't this work?" and that's a perfectly reasonable question, especially given that this behavior is a bit of a quirk.