# Matrix Multiplication with template parameters in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11, matrix

I have a self-defined `Matrix` class and want to overload operator `*` to do matrix multiplication:

```
template< int R, int C> 
class Matrix{
   int *_mat;
   int _size;
public:
   Matrix(){ _size = R*C; _mat = new int[_size]{0}; }
   ~Matrix(){ delete []_mat; }
   Matrix &operator=(const Matrix & m){/*...*/}
   //...
   template< int D2, int D1 > using matrix_t = int[D2][D1];
   template<int R2, int C2>
   Matrix<R,C2> operator*(const matrix_t<R2,C2> &mat)
   {
       Matrix<R,C2> result;
       for(int r = 0; r < R; r++)
       {
           for(int c = 0; c < C2; c++)
           {
               for( int i; i < C; i++ ){
                  /*do multiplication...
                    result._mat[r*C2+c] = ...
                  */
               }
           }
       }
       return result;
   }      
   //...
};
```

Then the problem comes with `Matrix<R,C2> result`. The `result` becomes a outside object of the class. So I cannot access its private member using like `result._mat[r*C2+c]`.

What is the solution( without changing access permission) to define my function of matrix multiplication in this class?

Comment: you should be able to access the private member of another object from inside the same class.  So result._mat[r*C2+c] should actually work?

Comment: @Richard `result._mat[r*C2+c]` dose not work in this case on VS2013. What do you mean by 'access the private member of another object' ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008200/a-private-variable-can-be-accessed-from-another-object-of-the-same-type

Comment: but if you have different templates (with different template args) then the compiler won't see it as the "same class"

Comment: @Shindou `Matrix< int R, int C>`  and `Matrix< int R2, int C>` are not the same type.  Just because the template is `Matrix` doesn't make the types the same.  So you need to rethink your design.

Comment: I think your template can declare itself as a friend to get around the problem that being instantiated with different template parameters makes it a different class.  I haven't done such things myself, so I'd need to experiment with the syntax in order to make this a real answer.

Comment: @JSF I have just tried this effort but can not work it out. Have you worked it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify an operator so you can externally set the values of the matrix.  Note you won't be able to use `operator []` - since you can only use that with one argument (ref [C++ [] array operator with multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936399/c-array-operator-with-multiple-arguments))

```
   int& operator() (int row, int col) { 
     // todo: check array bounds
     return _mat[C*row+col];
   }
```

Usage:

```
 result(r,c) = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, you can just write function like `set`

```
void set(int index, int value)
{
   // check index
   _mat[index] = value;
}
```

And then in multiplication function just call `result.set(...)`. Instead of

```
result._mat[r*C2+c] = ...
```

just

```
result.set(r*C2+c, ...);
```

This situation is since `Result` is object of type `Matrix<R, C2>`, that is not the same type as `Matrix<R, C>`, so you cannot access private members of type `Matrix<R, C2>` in member function of type `Matrix<R, C>`.

Comment: The type of `*this` in your example is  `Matrix<R,C>` and thus could not assign to `result`...

Comment: `result._mat[...] = value;` in `void set(int, int, int)` then call `result.set(..)`? Somehow I can not understand this usage...

Comment: I'm confused with the `result` in function `void set(int, int, int)` since it is neither declared inside the function nor passed by argument list...By the way I think @Richard just gave a nice method..