# Why can access directly to private "property" in Visual C++? No encapsulate?

Tags: visual-c++

I have class like below in VC++:

```
class Student{
int id;
char *name;
public:
Student(){}

int compare(Student s){
 return strcmp(name, s.name)
}

}
```

I feel so strange, I can access direct to "name" of "s" without getter/setter, is there something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [With a private modifier, why can the member in other objects be accessed directly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396846/with-a-private-modifier-why-can-the-member-in-other-objects-be-accessed-directl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compare` is part of `Student`, of course it can access the private members of `Student`. Privacy applies to things *outside* of `Student`, not inside it.

If you're wondering why you can access `name` on `s`, it's because `s` is still a `Student`. Privacy is not instance-specific, it applies to the class. Code that has access to private information within `Student` has access to that information within *all* instances of `Student`, not just the one it's attached to.