# What's the reason for protected member accessibility additional check in C++?

Tags: c++

I just run to this issue, and know from the C++ standard define it as following (emphasize mine)

> An additional access check beyond those described earlier in Clause 11
>   is applied when a non-static data member or non-static member function
>   is a protected member of its naming class (11.2)115 As described
>   earlier, access to a protected member is granted because the reference
>   occurs in a friend or member of some class C. If the access is to form
>   a pointer to member (5.3.1), the nested-name-specifier shall denote C
>   or a class derived from C. All other accesses involve a (possibly
>   implicit) object expression (5.2.5). **In this case, the class of the
>   object expression shall be C or a class derived from C.**

Code snippet:

```
class Base
{
protected: 
    int i;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    // I cannot define it as void memfunc(Derived* obj) because of signature requirement.
    void memfunc(Base* obj) 
    {
       obj->i = 0;  // ERROR, cannot access private member via Base*
       Derived* dobj = (Derived*)(obj);
       dobj->i = 0; // OK
    }
};
```

So what's the reason for this check? Why C++ standard bother to limit access protected member via base class pointer?

Not Duplicate to: [Accessing protected members in a derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247671/accessing-protected-members-in-a-derived-class), I want to ask for the reason to prohibit it in standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because you derive from a `Base` doesn't mean you should be allowed to access protected member of any other class deriving from `Base`. Imagine a class `Derived2` provided by a library which inherits from `Base`. This way you'll be able to get a base object of `Derived2` and do whatever you want with it in the code of `Derived`.

So basically the standard ensures that you only modify protected members that you inherited and not mess with the integrity of unrelated siblings classes.

Comment: Note that the "workaround" in the question (casting to `Derived`) is Undefined Behavior when `obj` actually pointed to a `Derived2`. And you can't do a `dynamic_cast` since `Base` isn't polymorphic.