# C++ class inheritance setting "classA" data member equal to "ClassB"

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, member-functions

I'm trying to have a member function of classA set valuea to what ever valueb of classB is. I don't really have a full grasp of inheritance so forgive me if it's a simple or stupid mistake. Also Would it be easier to make the convert function a friend of both classes instead?

```
class B
{
    protected:
    int valueb;

public:
        B() { }
        B(int x) {valueb=x;}
};

class A: public B
{
    int valuea;
public:
    A():B() {}
    A(int x):B(x) {valuea=x;}
    void convert(B x)
    {
        valuea = x.valueb;
    }
    int getValue() {return valuea;}

};


int main( )
{
    A a(1);
    B b(2);

    a.convert(b);

    cout << a.getValue() << endl;
}
```

Comment: `class A` cannot access `valueb` from the parameter since it's protected. But `A` already is a `B`, so `valuea = B::valueb;` works. I don't know though if this matches your intend. See a working sample: http://ideone.com/NiQQAF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question would be more readily answered if you had stated the problem you are trying to solve with this design, but I'll throw in a few cents.

> I'm trying to have a member function of class A set valuea to what ever
>   valueb of class B is.

This doesn't make much sense as A inherits from B. An A *is a* B. It would make more sense if an A had B as a part, i.e.

```
class A{
    B partOfA;
```

Your name convert suggests that you might want to convert an object of type B to an object of type A, this is also quite odd but you can do it by having a constructor

```
A(const B& b):B(b){}
```

So instead of doing a "conversion" you create a new object

```
B b;
A a(b);
```

If your only goal is to access `x.valueb` from B you need a public accessor member in B. See for instance [Accessing protected members in a derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247671/accessing-protected-members-in-a-derived-class)

Comment: Hey thanks, This was just a simple lab question for a class I'm taking. I was just over thinking it trying to use the stuff we were going over. I didn't even think of just adding an accessor function but that is obviously the way to go. sorry for the confusion.