# How can I implements "operator+=" in derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

Given the following classes:

```
class A { 
int a;
public:
//..
};

class B : public A {
int b;
public:  
//.....
};
```

How can I implements `operator+=` in `class B` so that given `B b1(.. , ..);` and  `B b2(.. , .. );` If I will do `b1+=b2;` so I will get in `b1` the following value for his fields:

> b1.a = b1.a + b2.a   ,**and** b1.b = b1.b + b2.b

In the following case:

```
class A { 
protected:
int a;
public:
//..
};

class B : public A {
int b;
public:  
B& operator+=(const B& bb){
this->a += bb.a; // error..
this->b += bb.b;
return *this;
};
```

My problem is how can I get the fields of `class A`..?

Comment: Did you try to research operator overloading? What did you try? Where'd you get stuck?

Comment: See "Binary arithmetic operators" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421708

Comment: See "Effective C++" and "More Effective C++" by Scott Meyers.

Comment: @scohe001 Yes, I try to research operator overloading. But in this case, I don't understand how can I get (without define the field of `class A` as protected or public) the field of `class A`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews My question is in case of inheritance (for the derived class). I don't to do it for a simple class.

Comment: Define a method, let's call it `assign_plus` as protected in your base class.  In your derived class' `operator+=()`, call the base class `assign_plus` method.  The `assign_plus` should only manipulate variables in the base class and make no other assumptions.  Don't try inheriting overloaded operators.

Comment: Are you against having a public `operator+=` in your derived class that just adds the `a`'s?

Comment: You mean maybe to public fields in the base class? (I don't understand your question, because that `operator+=` is a public in my question. No?)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Can you explain it with answer about the question please? I will be happy to understand your idea :) .

Comment: @AskMath see my answer...

Comment: @scohe001 Ok , and you understand what Thomas mean while he said " Don't try inheriting overloaded operators." ? [and Why no to do it?]

Comment: I'm not sure why @ThomasMatthews was telling you not to inherit overloaded operators, that's not something I've ever heard. I could easily just be missing something though...

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](https://ideone.com/avYgmn). The original code works fine for me (after correcting a few syntax mistakes that prevented compiling).

Comment: @RemyLebeau OP mentions they want `a` to be private but showed they can get it to work if it's not. This is their issue. See their first comment on this post.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's not like in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247671/accessing-protected-members-in-a-derived-class (But anyway, I want the fields will be as a private like that I mentioned in the comments above).

Comment: @AskMath that information belonged in your question, not in comments. Nothing in your question says anything about that requirement, or even the exact error you are dealing with. Besides, `A::a` is `private` by default, but you explicitly declared it as `protected`, so `B` has access to it. So what is the REAL problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wanted that the field of `A` will be private for provide "hide" for the class. In addition, I thought that it's will make to error like in the link that I added (like in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247671/accessing-protected-members-in-a-derived-class) , In fcat, why it's not a same to the case that provided in this link?

Comment: @RemyLebeau And it's what that I did in the first example.. (The second example was for scohe001  - he asked it). ***But***, why you don't get error while you do it with protected? it's not the case that provided in the link that I added ?

Comment: @AskMath stop posting details in **comments** and start EDITING YOUR QUESTION to have the relevant information. The code IN YOUR QUESTION declares `a` as `protected` and not as `private`, that is why the code WORKS

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok , can you explain why you don't get error?

Comment: @AskMath because `B` is using `public` inheritance, and so it has access to `A`'s `protected` members.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174683/discussion-between-askmath-and-remy-lebeau).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `A` its own `operator+=`! Then you just have to call it from `B`:

```
class A { 
private:
    int a;
public:
    A(int a) : a(a) { } 

    A& operator+=(const A &other) {
        a += other.a;
        return *this;
    }   
};

class B : public A { 
private:
    int b;
public:
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), b(b) { } 

    B& operator+=(const B &other) {
        A::operator+=(other);
        b += other.b;
        return *this;
    }   
};
```

See a working example [here](https://ideone.com/tVqsoE) (ideone link).

Comment: Firstly, thank you about the answer. Secondly, can you explain this line : `this->A::operator+=(other);`  , what is say `this->A` , after all, `A` is a class..

Comment: @AskMath the `this->` is optional, but I prefer to make it explicit. `A::` means "In the scope of `A`..." So `A::operator+=(...` means "call the function `operator+=()` in the scope of `A`." We have to be specific since if I'd just done `operator+=(other)` it would've called the function we're writing!

Comment: @AskMath First off, you don't need to use `this->` everywhere, that is considered bad form.  Second, calling `A::operator+=()` is telling the compiler to call the inherited `operator+=` from the `A` class, not the `operator+=` in the current `B` class (that would lead to an endless recursive loop!)

Comment: Didn't realize it was considered bad form @RemyLebeau. I'll edit it out.