# Access directly protected field in a base class

Tags: c++

The following code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    protected :
        int a;
    public :
        Base() {};
        Base(int x) :a(x) {};
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        Derived(int x) : Base(x) {};
 };


int main() {
    Derived b(11);
    int x;
    x=b.a;
}
```

does not compile because *'int Base::a'* is protected within this context. 
I know that the Derived class can not access a member of a **different** Base **instance**.
I read the following post [Accessing protected members in a derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3247671/7462275) (and others related posts). So I try different things. For example, I add a new constructor for Derived class.

```
Derived() {Base(static_cast<Derived*>(this)->a);};
```

But, as expected, without success.
Is there a mean (some modifers or something else) to access `Base` class protected field **directly** (`a` field in `Base` must be `protected`)?

Comment: I think you can create in the Derived class a method `getA()` public and inside the method, you call the `return a;`

Comment: @vincenzopalazza. I know that. But, I must create a method for each field I want to access. And, I would like to avoid that.

Comment: `main()` can't access a protected member of the base class unless `Base` declares `main()` as a `friend`..  In your example, only member functions of `Derived` can access `protected` members of `Base`.

Comment: The entire point of making the members protected in the base class is that you should not access them from the outside.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. What do you want to achieve here? The problem is just `x = b.a;` statement. And you can easily solve it with `using Base::x` in `Derived` or providing a *getter* for `a` member. How different instances of `Base` are related in this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the access specifier using a `using` directive

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    protected :
        int a;
    public :
        Base() {};
        Base(int x) :a(x) {};
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        Derived(int x) : Base(x) {};
        using Base::a;
 };


int main() {
    Derived b(11);
    int x;
    x=b.a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am aware that `a` becomes public when it is accessed from `Derived` object but this solution is suitable for my needs.